# Spring Shared Services & Repositories - Best Practises

Tags: java, spring

My Company has multiple spring projects, some of which do similiar / the same things. Task is to split and merge them where possible. Simplfied, there are following projects:

**core**

- Core project, does a lot of things. (Spring project)

**shared**

- Project with shared entities and other shared POJOs

**tool1**

- Some tool (Spring project)
- Contains duplicated / copied services and repositories

**tool2**

- Some other tool (Spring project)
- Contains duplicated / copied services and repositories

**tools**

- Yet another tool (Spring project)

Plan is to merge duplicated / copied services from core, tool1, tool2 into shared. That way all the projects have access to the same services and repositories and nothing needs to be copy pasted.

Is there any reason to not do it like this? Is it maybe bad practice, or are there any issues by sharing services and repository classes? Would different projects for services and repositories be a better alternative?

Comment: IMHO, it is ok, but the challenge will be to deal with versioning of the shared project in other calling projects. Which is not that tricky with maven/gradle, artifact repo (nexus) and git

Comment: As such it would be possible, but I think it is not something suitable, for the simple fact that you could maintain all your services if you make a gateway that redirects to each microservice based on the request. You would save the cost in time and money of merging all the code.

Comment: The problem is the core project contains some scheduled services. One goal is to have multiple instances running of the core project (load balancing).  Those schedule services would run twice, this would mess up quite some things. Thats why we want to move them to the tools project, but then some core services and repos are unavailable to the said scheduled services

Comment: Also the different projects (tool) currently have copied services and repos of the core project, we also want to get rid of those